# Finding shortest path algorithms

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, shortest-path

First, thank you for taking time to read this post.

> **Problem:**
>
> > Find the shortest path from **i** to **j** (i != j; i, j >= 0) from a given array, whereas you can only move **left**, **right**, or **go to** any element which has the same value to current element.
>
> **Example:**
>   I have an array contains 9 numbers: `int arr[9] = {7, 2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7, 0}`;
>   `int i = 1, j = 6;`
>
> According to above declarations, i want to go from `arr[i]` to `arr[j]` (2 to 9) then the shortest path is `arr[1]`(2) -> `arr[0]`(1st 7) -> `arr[7]`(2nd 7) -> `arr[6]`(9) (total steps: 3)
>
> **More Example:**
>
> `int arr[9] = {7, 2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7, 0}`;
>   `int i = 7, j = 8;` steps: 1 (7 -> 8)
>
> `int arr[9] = {8, 2, 0, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7, 0}`;
>   `int i = 0, j = 8;` steps: 3 (0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 8)
>
> `int arr[9] = {1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 22, 9, 8, 6}`;
>   `int i = 2, j = 7;` steps: 5 (2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7)

I was trying to traverse all the elements in array (except **i** & **j**) to see whether any element have the same value and closest to **j**, but i'm end up getting more cases to deal with. Hope you guys can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Have you encountered [A*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)?

Comment: @lenik just help me solve this problem with your own ideas, i think mine is not gonna work.

Comment: Is this for a class on graphs? Can you model this as a graph, and have you seen any shortest-path algorithm in class?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i've never encountered this before, but i'm going to take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: @JesperJuhl why not just Dijkstra? There is no good estimate here to plug in A*.

Comment: @MarcGlisse this problem is the first shortest-path algorithm i've ever met so i'm trying to understand it.

Comment: btw this is my very first post on stackoverflow, why my post getting downvoted, am i doing something unclear or wrongly describe? Just let me know so i can do better next time :(

Comment: @MarcGlisse I was just trying to point OP towards a class of algorithms..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the easiest way is to:

1. create another array, call it `distance` and fill it with value `-1`.
2. set `distance[i] = 0`, since it's free to move from the element to itself
3. loop over the `distance` and for every existing number that's not `-1` fill the element on the left and on the right with the number of the current element + 1 (do that only if the elements on left/right are equal to `-1`)
4. for the newly filled elements, find the elements with the same value in `array` and set the `distance` for them to the same value as you just did on the step 3.

Once you loop over this enough times, you'll have the array `distance` fully filled, which will tell you how far is any element from the element `array[i]`.

You may exit loop early, if you just need the `distance[j]` and you have already found it.

Comment: @DuongPham if you find the answer useful, you may accept and / or upvote

Comment: just leave my code here in case someone needs it. 
https://gist.github.com/pnd280/859e2e63c136fe9e330ed4f036ebbcde